# Java Backend sending properties not retrieved by the typescript frontend

Tags: jwt, backend, rest

I don't understand why in my http Get Call, a properties is send by the backend but not receive in the frontend.

I have this class :

```
/**
 * A Saison.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "saison")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Saison implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^2[0-9]{3}$")
    @Column(name = "annee_saison", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String anneeSaison;

    @Column(name = "est_active_saison")
    private Boolean estActiveSaison;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_lundi")
    private Boolean paramJourLundi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_mardi")
    private Boolean paramJourMardi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_mercredi")
    private Boolean paramJourMercredi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_jeudi")
    private Boolean paramJourJeudi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_vendredi")
    private Boolean paramJourVendredi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_samedi")
    private Boolean paramJourSamedi;

    @Column(name = "param_jour_dimanche")
    private Boolean paramJourDimanche;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_janvier")
    private Boolean paramMoisJanvier;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_fevrier")
    private Boolean paramMoisFevrier;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_mars")
    private Boolean paramMoisMars;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_avril")
    private Boolean paramMoisAvril;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_mai")
    private Boolean paramMoisMai;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_juin")
    private Boolean paramMoisJuin;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_juillet")
    private Boolean paramMoisJuillet;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_aout")
    private Boolean paramMoisAout;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_septembre")
    private Boolean paramMoisSeptembre;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_octobre")
    private Boolean paramMoisOctobre;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_novembre")
    private Boolean paramMoisNovembre;

    @Column(name = "param_mois_decembre")
    private Boolean paramMoisDecembre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "saison")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "saison" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Seance> seances = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Saison id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getAnneeSaison() {
        return this.anneeSaison;
    }

    public Saison anneeSaison(String anneeSaison) {
        this.anneeSaison = anneeSaison;
        return this;
    }

    public void setAnneeSaison(String anneeSaison) {
        this.anneeSaison = anneeSaison;
    }

    public Boolean getEstActiveSaison() {
        return this.estActiveSaison;
    }

    public Saison estActiveSaison(Boolean estActiveSaison) {
        this.estActiveSaison = estActiveSaison;
        return this;
    }

    public void setEstActiveSaison(Boolean estActiveSaison) {
        this.estActiveSaison = estActiveSaison;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourLundi() {
        return paramJourLundi;
    }

    public void setParamJourLundi(Boolean paramJourLundi) {
        this.paramJourLundi = paramJourLundi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourMardi() {
        return paramJourMardi;
    }

    public void setParamJourMardi(Boolean paramJourMardi) {
        this.paramJourMardi = paramJourMardi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourMercredi() {
        return paramJourMercredi;
    }

    public void setParamJourMercredi(Boolean paramJourMercredi) {
        this.paramJourMercredi = paramJourMercredi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourJeudi() {
        return paramJourJeudi;
    }

    public void setParamJourJeudi(Boolean paramJourJeudi) {
        this.paramJourJeudi = paramJourJeudi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourVendredi() {
        return paramJourVendredi;
    }

    public void setParamJourVendredi(Boolean paramJourVendredi) {
        this.paramJourVendredi = paramJourVendredi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourSamedi() {
        return paramJourSamedi;
    }

    public void setParamJourSamedi(Boolean paramJourSamedi) {
        this.paramJourSamedi = paramJourSamedi;
    }

    public Boolean getParamJourDimanche() {
        return paramJourDimanche;
    }

    public void setParamJourDimanche(Boolean paramJourDimanche) {
        this.paramJourDimanche = paramJourDimanche;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisJanvier() {
        return paramMoisJanvier;
    }

    public void setParamMoisJanvier(Boolean paramMoisJanvier) {
        this.paramMoisJanvier = paramMoisJanvier;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisFevrier() {
        return paramMoisFevrier;
    }

    public void setParamMoisFevrier(Boolean paramMoisFevrier) {
        this.paramMoisFevrier = paramMoisFevrier;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisMars() {
        return paramMoisMars;
    }

    public void setParamMoisMars(Boolean paramMoisMars) {
        this.paramMoisMars = paramMoisMars;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisAvril() {
        return paramMoisAvril;
    }

    public void setParamMoisAvril(Boolean paramMoisAvril) {
        this.paramMoisAvril = paramMoisAvril;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisMai() {
        return paramMoisMai;
    }

    public void setParamMoisMai(Boolean paramMoisMai) {
        this.paramMoisMai = paramMoisMai;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisJuin() {
        return paramMoisJuin;
    }

    public void setParamMoisJuin(Boolean paramMoisJuin) {
        this.paramMoisJuin = paramMoisJuin;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisJuillet() {
        return paramMoisJuillet;
    }

    public void setParamMoisJuillet(Boolean paramMoisJuillet) {
        this.paramMoisJuillet = paramMoisJuillet;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisAout() {
        return paramMoisAout;
    }

    public void setParamMoisAout(Boolean paramMoisAout) {
        this.paramMoisAout = paramMoisAout;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisSeptembre() {
        return paramMoisSeptembre;
    }

    public void setParamMoisSeptembre(Boolean paramMoisSeptembre) {
        this.paramMoisSeptembre = paramMoisSeptembre;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisOctobre() {
        return paramMoisOctobre;
    }

    public void setParamMoisOctobre(Boolean paramMoisOctobre) {
        this.paramMoisOctobre = paramMoisOctobre;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisNovembre() {
        return paramMoisNovembre;
    }

    public void setParamMoisNovembre(Boolean paramMoisNovembre) {
        this.paramMoisNovembre = paramMoisNovembre;
    }

    public Boolean getParamMoisDecembre() {
        return paramMoisDecembre;
    }

    public void setParamMoisDecembre(Boolean paramMoisDecembre) {
        this.paramMoisDecembre = paramMoisDecembre;
    }

    public Set<Seance> getSeances() {
        return this.seances;
    }

    public Saison seances(Set<Seance> seances) {
        this.setSeances(seances);
        return this;
    }

    public Saison addSeance(Seance seance) {
        this.seances.add(seance);
        seance.setSaison(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Saison removeSeance(Seance seance) {
        this.seances.remove(seance);
        seance.setSaison(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setSeances(Set<Seance> seances) {
        if (this.seances != null) {
            this.seances.forEach(i -> i.setSaison(null));
        }
        if (seances != null) {
            seances.forEach(i -> i.setSaison(this));
        }
        this.seances = seances;
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Saison)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Saison) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Saison{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", anneeSaison='" + getAnneeSaison() + "'" +
            ", estActiveSaison='" + getEstActiveSaison() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

And the Link Entity Seance :

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "seance")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public class Seance implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
        private Long id;
    
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "date_seance", nullable = false)
        private LocalDate dateSeance;
    
        @NotNull
        @Pattern(regexp = "(^0{0,1}[0-9]|^[1]{1}[0-9]|^[2]{1}[0-3])H[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$")
        @Column(name = "heure_debut_seance", nullable = false)
        private String heureDebutSeance;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Saison saison;
    
        // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public Seance id(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }
    
        public LocalDate getDateSeance() {
            return this.dateSeance;
        }
    
        public Seance dateSeance(LocalDate dateSeance) {
            this.dateSeance = dateSeance;
            return this;
        }
    
        public void setDateSeance(LocalDate dateSeance) {
            this.dateSeance = dateSeance;
        }
    
        public String getHeureDebutSeance() {
            return this.heureDebutSeance;
        }
    
        public Seance heureDebutSeance(String heureDebutSeance) {
            this.heureDebutSeance = heureDebutSeance;
            return this;
        }
    
        public void setHeureDebutSeance(String heureDebutSeance) {
            this.heureDebutSeance = heureDebutSeance;
        }
    
        public Saison getSaison() {
            return this.saison;
        }
    
        public Seance saison(Saison saison) {
            this.setSaison(saison);
            return this;
        }
    
        public void setSaison(Saison saison) {
            this.saison = saison;
        }
    
        // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof Seance)) {
                return false;
            }
            return id != null && id.equals(((Seance) o).id);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
            return getClass().hashCode();
        }
    
        // prettier-ignore
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Seance{" +
                "id=" + getId() +
                ", dateSeance='" + getDateSeance() + "'" +
                ", heureDebutSeance='" + getHeureDebutSeance() + "'" +
                "}";
        }
    }
```

And this resource

```
@GetMapping("/saison/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Saison> getSaisons(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Saisons : {}", id);
    Optional<Saison> saisons = saisonRepository.findById(id);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(saisons);
}
```

All properties are available including "seances"
[image]

In the frontend, I have a method for call the service :

```
changementSaisonDansListe(): void {
    if (this.saisonIdSelectionnee) {
      this.saisonService.find(this.saisonIdSelectionnee).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.body) {
          this.saisonSelectionnee = res.body;
        }
      }, () => {
        // TODO Remplacer avec Gestion des erreurs
        // this.loadAll();
      })
    }
  }
```

And the service that points to the back :

```
      find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http.get<ISaison>(`${this.resourceUrlSaison}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

The endpoint :

```
  public resourceUrlSaison = this.applicationConfigService.getEndpointFor('api/saison');
```

But when i check the content of the service return, properties "seance" is always null :
[image]

**EDIT 1**

The same with SOPAUI :
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Very strange ... if I put my backend in debug and I put a breakpoint before the return and I display in the debug console the value of the property "session", they are displayed on SOAPUi but only the ones I saw on the debugging console (and not the others)!

Comment: This seems to be a problem on the backend side. I am doing the test with SOAPUI and I also have null in the "seance" property.

How is JSON created during HTTP GET? Is there a particular configuration that I haven't seen?

Answer (score 0):

Found, my entity was not up to date with all the attributes (including "seance") because I added them after their generation ... it seems to work!